# UI building, how to input an array of number in the Manipulate function?

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate

I'm trying to build a simple financial app with Mathematica, i'm having problems with UI building (nothing fancy, it's just an hobby). [Here](https://pastebin.com/iXFacN8G) is the code.

The problem is with the Manipulate function, i wrote:

```
Manipulate[
 profit = GainsLong[entry, entryPrice, profitPoints, percentage],
 {entry},
 {entryPrice},
 {profitPoints},
 {percentage}
 ]
```

as `profitPoints` and `percentage` are both arrays of numbers, how can i set the code in a way that let me insert in the boxes something like "10, 20, 30" instead of "{10, 20, 30}"?

Also, i'd like the manipulate function to run the code only after i finish inserting the values.
When i insert the array of profitPoints, untill i insert the percentages i get a wall of errors.

Comment: Apart from your question, I noticed that your function has side-effects, in that it modifies the value of a global variable (`profit`) from within the function (incidentally, this also causes the Manipulate to continuously re-evaluate). That is pretty much *guaranteed* to cause a headache at some point. Can you refactor the code so it outputs a value you can store, without modifying a global variable?

Comment: Thanks @MarcoB, i started wondering why it needed 80% of CPU1 while not doing anything. That may be the problem.